# Можно ли в одной базе данных sqlite3 создавать несколько таблиц?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

Можно ли в одной базе данных  sqlite3 создавать несколько таблиц?

Comment: Наверное это была бы не база данных, если бы в ней нельзя было создавать "любое" количество таблиц...

Comment: примите ответ, если он вам помог — галочка около ответа

Answer (score 3):

Why not?

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
''')
db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE another_contacts (
    contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);
''')
```